# Getting SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: when running docker with sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am running docker with following config

```yaml
web:
  image: ca9a385372b0
  volumes:
    - .:/src
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  container_name: web
  links:
    - mysql
mysql:
  image: 7666f75adb6b
  environment:
  container_name: mysql
  ports:
   - "6603:3306"
  volumes:
   - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

After starting the containers I am able to connect fine to the mysql on port 6603 through my main terminal.

```
mysql -uuser -p -h127.0.0.1 -P6603
```

But I get following error when doing through my nodejs app container. I have linked the containers. I can see that its trying to connect to the mysql container using the internal IP and all.

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.3:6603

I also checked the permission on mysql container and see this:

```sql
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql container is exposing port 3306 (as seen in your port mapping, which connects external port 6603 to the exposed container port 3306).

```yaml
ports:
  - "6603:3306"
```

We know that is correct, because you are able to use it from outside and connect to mysql.

```
mysql -uuser -p -h127.0.0.1 -P6603
```

Your node app is attempting to connect to the external port 6603 (as we can see from the error message).

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.3:**6603**

But node is operating *inside* the docker network, not outside. It has no access to the externally mapped ports.

**Solution:** Tell the node app to use port 3306.

Comment: thank you.  that worked. Still getting used to understanding docker.